# CentOS 6 download impossible?

Tags: centos

I do not understand, how to download CentOS or CentOS6. We've tried to find the ISO-Images for several hours, but the whole process is extremely complicated. **The CentOS website is a real catastrophe** !

Can anyone provide me a download link for CentOS 6 ?

http://www.centos.org/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the mirror list over at http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6/isos/
Pick either i386 or x86_64 depending on your needs and then pick a mirror that's close to your physical location to (usually) get the best possible download speed.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the greatest of website but I don't see how you could spend several hours and not find the [public mirrors](http://www.centos.org/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=30) list. From there you should be able to choose a continent near you and find a relatively local mirror.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://mirrors.arsc.edu/centos/6/isos/x86_64/) is a link for all iso of CentOS 6 x86_64, but [here](http://www.centos.org/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=30) you can find the complete mirror list. Choose the nearest mirror.

Answer (score 0):

Many people (eg the heroic Iain) have pointed you to the mirror list, which is absolutely right.  You need to **pay attention to the column near the end**, which says "Direct DVD Downloads".  **If that value isn't "yes", you won't find the DVD there, only the .torrent file**.  Pick a mirror from the list that has "yes" in that column, click on the HTTP link immediately to the right, then click through to `6`, `isos`, the architecture of your choice, and download the `DVD.iso`.